# Simulate multiple inheritance in PHP

Tags: php, multiple-inheritance

Assuming I have 2 classes

```
Class A {
    public function doA(){
        echo "Im A";
    }
}
Class B {
    public function doB(){
        echo "Im B";
    }
}
```

write Class C, in order that the following code runs:

```
  $c = new C();
  $c->doA();
  $c->doB();
```

and outputs:

```
>> Im A
>> Im B
```

This was in a test, and the conditions where:

- use no static calls
- you can't modify class A or class B

so I wrote:

```
Class C {

       public function doA() {
             $a = new A();
             $a->doA();
       }

       public function doB() {
             $b = new B();
             $b->doB();
       }

  }
```

So apparently I was wrong as it can be "more optimized"

can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: `class C extends A,B{}`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat you can't do that in PHP.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari: Never mind, then. :-)  I knew you could `implement` multiple things, I thought you could `extend` multiple things too.  Guess you can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could keep instances of `A` and `B` instead of instantiating them each time.

```
class C {
       private $a, $b;

       public __construct() {
             $this->a = new A();
             $this->b = new B();
       }

       public function doA() {
             $this->a->doA();
       }

       public function doB() {
             $this->b->doB();
       }
}
```

Comment: wooooow
nice and easy... :D

Answer (score 2):

PHP has no "native" multiple inheritance, but you can achieve something similar to it by using [traits](http://php.net/traits).

```
Trait A {
    public function doA(){
        echo "Im A";
    }
}

Trait B {
    public function doB(){
        echo "Im B";
    }
}

Class C {
    use A, B;
}

$c = new C;
$c->doA();
$c->doB();
```

Note that this would require at least **PHP 5.4**.

Comment: I was not allowed to modify Class A or Class B

Comment: Then go with @rid answer.

Comment: He can't modify classes A and B, and that's not really the ideal way to use traits.

Comment: Why not, it is just an example though.

Comment: Because it was a test, and those were the rules specified.

Comment: Actually @ollieread that's exactly how to use traits. I'm not sure why everyone is capitalizing the keywords `class` and `trait` in this thread though. Hope you realize you're just *getting away with it* as [none of them](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) start w/ capital letters.

Comment: Well PHP is not case sensitive for keywords, so you could write it all uppercase if you liked.

Answer (score 1):

To do it without modifying classes, the best and optimised option would be as follows.

```
class C {
    private $a;
    private $b;

    public __construct() {
        $this->a = new A();
        $this->b = new B();
    }

    public function __call($method, $arguments = array()) {
        if(method_exists($this->as, $method)) {
            return call_user_func(array($this->a, $method));
        }
    }
}
```

The above is also future proof, so adding new methods would also follow.

While you were told not to modify classes A and B, the correct way to do this would be by having B extend A, then having C extend B, like below.

```
class A {
    public function doA(){
        echo "Im A";
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public function doB(){
        echo "Im B";
    }
}
class C extends B {

}

$c = new C();
$c->doA();
$c->doB();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the "correct" way. It's a way, with advantages and disadvantages (just as `__call` is not necessarily "the" way, but just a way, again with advantages and disadvantages).

Comment: Tbh, the question is a rather broad one. Faced with the situation I'd edit classes A & B. There's no reason to not.

Comment: well, it was a job interview xD and I got rejected mustly for doing the cascade inheritance thing :(

Comment: Sure there is. One big disadvantage is that you'd add a dependency, making `B` depend on `A` even if it doesn't have to. Another disadvantage is that you'd get a deeper inheritance tree, making maintenance harder in the long run (the `__call` approach is much bigger maintenance issue though). The only advantage I see is that you write less code. Again, each way of doing this has advantages and disadvantages, and there's always a reason not to do it one way or another.

Comment: The problem with job interview tests is that they often pose you with problems you rarely face.

Comment: 'Optimized' is a bit of a red herring here. If you mean you have to type less, you're correct. If you mean the code will run faster, you're wrong. There are various tradeoffs in using `__call`, but it does make sense in many cases, thus this is just an alternative approach. It does belong in the list of answers for sure though.